# Pivotal Cloud Foundry - Working with Service Registry : Container to Container communication blocked

Tags: microservices

I have around 9 microservices deployed in PCF and in our organization due to security constraints container to container communication is blocked.
All the microservices are on a loadbalancer and single instance mostly.

Should I use the Service registry provided by PCF for internal microservice communication or it is not mandated to use Service registry in this scenario.
Should I use Feign Interface to call another microservice or can use regular resttemplate to call the microservice ? Whats the advantage of using Service registry in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the microservice through feign and resttemplate is not recommended.  Microservice communication should be asynchronous,  hence use messaging interface like SQS if you are using aws or tibco EMS( JMS).

Hence push the messages instead of direct calling on http in messaging System.

Comment: Thanks Abhay for suggesting SQS but assuming http communication and synchronous behaviour what would be the best between Feign and rest template given the constraints.

Comment: You will face issues with http call during load, most of the call will fail during peak load and there is no way for handling these calls. For Feign client only the callback will be called in case of http call failure. Messaging service is the best way for handling the peak load and microservice service interaction should be minimul over http that is the best microservice design practise.

Comment: Even you want to use HTTP communication, Feign client is the best dont use the rest-template it is completely obslete.